# React Error "Uncaught TypeError: _react.default.createContext is not a function at Object.<anonymous>"

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I am having trouble with my project. Below is my `package.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "my_project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
      "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --host 0.0.0.0",
      "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && mkdir -p dist/app && cp -r src/app/assets dist/app",
      "start:prod": "node server.js"
    },
    "author": "Abb",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "adminlte-reactjs": "1.0.1",
      "auth0-js": "^9.7.3",
      "auth0-lock": "^11.8.1",
      "awesome-phonenumber": "1.2.0",
      "axios": "0.15.3",
      "babel-cli": "6.18.0",
      "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.15.0",
      "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.16.0",
      "ckeditor-react": "^1.0.1",
      "classnames": "2.2.5",
      "download-file": "^0.1.5",
      "express": "4.15.0",
      "if-env": "1.0.0",
      "jquery": "3.1.1",
      "jsbarcode": "3.8.0",
      "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
      "lodash": "4.17.4",
      "react": "^15.4.1",
      "react-addons-css-transition-group": "15.4.1",
      "react-bootstrap": "0.30.0",
      "react-bootstrap-date-picker": "5.0.1",
      "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker": "3.2.2",
      "react-csv": "^1.0.8",
      "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
      "react-file-download": "0.3.2",
      "react-print": "1.3.1",
      "react-router": "3.0.0",
      "react-rte": "^0.14.2",
      "react-select": "1.0.0-rc.2",
      "react-telephone-input": "3.8.6",
      "react-tinymce": "^0.6.0",
      "semantic-ui-css": "2.2.4",
      "semantic-ui-react": "0.63.5",
      "sematable": "1.4.6",
      "superagent": "3.3.1",
      "validator": "6.2.0",
      "react-datetime": "^2.16.3",
      "react-notifications": "^1.4.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel-core": "6.21.0",
      "babel-loader": "6.2.10",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "6.18.0",
      "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
      "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.18.0",
      "css-loader": "0.26.1",
      "dotenv-webpack": "1.4.2",
      "html-loader": "0.4.4",
      "react-css-modules": "4.1.0",
      "style-loader": "0.13.1",
      "webpack": "1.14.0",
      "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2"
    }
  }
```

I am getting below error in console and blank screen when I open my project:

```
bundle.js:127255 Uncaught TypeError: _react.default.createContext is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:127255)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:126574)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:126077)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:126034)
```

I can not update the version of react and react-dom as it will require to update the whole project. For now, I just want to fix the above error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is happening because of the version mismatch of the other packages with react. One of the packages is trying to access the react context feature but it's not available in react 15.4. To solve this either upgrade your react version to 16.4 or find which package is trying to use the React `context `feature and degrade that package.

Comment: @Rajiv I am not able to find the version in which package needs context. Do you have any idea how to do it?